# how to make std::array initialisation used in debug mode ignored in release model?

Tags: c++, macros, stdarray

I have *macro* called `DEVLOGGER`and `DEVLOGARRAYMSG`.
`DEVLOGGER` is responsible for calling a singleton function which logs the mssage that is passed.

`DEVLOGARRAYMSG`calls a singleton function that receives an `std::array` and creates a message. this message then passed to `DEVLOGGER` for logging.

The reason I have these *macros* is that because the logging only happens during debug mode. When the source is compiled in release mode, they are ignored.

```
#if _DEBUG
#undef DEVLOGGER
#define DEVLOGGER(message)   {            \
      DevLogger::Get().Log(message);}
#undef DEVLOGARRAYMSG
#define DEVLOGARRAYMSG(arr) {                  \
      DEVLOGGER(DevLogger::Get().CreateReelPosMsg(arr));}

#else
#undef DEVLOGGER
#define DEVLOGGER
#undef DEVLOGARRAYMSG
#define DEVLOGARRAYMSG
#endif /*_DEBUG*/
```

However, here is my problem.
consider this example,

```
 std::array<int, (size_t)REEL_MAX> arr1 = { 1,2,3,4,5};
 DEVLOGARRAYMSG(arr1);
```

When I'm running this in release mode, std array will be created even if the `DEVLOGARRAYMSG` call is ignored by the compiler during compilation.

I could perhaps use the `#if#endif` guards;

```
#if _DEBUG
     std::array<int, (size_t)REEL_MAX> arr1 = { 1,2,3,4,5};
     DEVLOGARRAYMSG(arr1)
#endif
```

But I am not really keen on this method because there is always possiblity the *#if #endif* guards can be accidentally misplaced/forgotten/removed throughout the development

If I could do something like;

```
DEVLOGARRAYMSG({1,2,3,4,5});
```

This would have been great but as far as i know this is not valid.
I would like to know how you guys deal with such issues

Comment: For my part I no longer use the C preprocessor, I use either SFINE or if constexpr. These idioms work well with C++ are more readable and work better with debuggers and static analysis.

Comment: Could you use `std::initializer_list` instead of `std::array`? Then `DEVLOGARRAYMSG({1,2,3,4,5});` should work.

Comment: @Galik if there is no other option yea that seems to be the only sensible solition. i think vectors can be initialised similar way iirc. never heard of the term SFINE Richard mentioned. i ll spend some time on that first and see how it goes.

Comment: @Yucel_K SFIN**A**E